# How to check username and password match laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am creating the simple login form using laravel 7.i want to check the username and password match.it is a match redirect the home. if it does not redirect the login page again show the error username or password does not match. I tried the below code I got the error Call to undefined method App\User::attempt()

**Login Controller.**

```
 public function check(Request $request)
    {
    
         $uname = $request->uname;
         $password = $request->password;
         $user = User::where('uname',$a)->get()->last();
         $pass = User::where('password',$b)->get()->last();
    
         if (User::attempt(array('uname' => $uname , 'password' => $password ))){
            return "success";
            }
            else {        
                return "Wrong Credentials";
            }  
    }
```

**view Login**

```
@extends('layout')
  
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h2>Login</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger"> 
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
   

  
     <div class="row">
     <form  action="{{ route('login.check') }}" method="POST">
     @csrf
        <div class="col-sm-4">

            <div class="left">
                <strong>UserName</strong>
                <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="UName">
            </div>
      

        
            <div class="left">
                <strong>Password</strong>
                <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="password" placeholder="Password"></textarea>
            </div>
        

        </br>
        <div class="left">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>         
        </div>

        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Model**  User

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to replace `User::attempt` with `auth()->attempt`

another thing you don't need to check `uname` and `passowrd` manually laravel do that for you inside the `attempt` method so it would be more efficient if
you delete those two lines

```
  $user = User::where('uname',$a)->get()->last();
  $pass = User::where('password',$b)->get()->last();
```

finally, depends on your `User` model you have `name` not `uname` so you need to update it like this

```
if (auth()->attempt(array('name' => $uname , 'password' => $password ))){
   return "success";
} else {        
   return "Wrong Credentials";
}
```

Comment: Call to a member function attempt() on null

Comment: if (auth()->user()->attempt(array('uname' => $a, 'password' => $b))){       error displayed Call to a member function attempt() on null

Comment: if (auth()->user()->attempt(array('uname' => $ $user , 'password' => $$pass))){  error displayed Call to a member function attempt() on null

Comment: sorry my mistake i update it to `auth()->attempt`

Comment: ya but if i enter correct username and password also msg displayed Wrong Credentials

Comment: i changed but same msg Wrong Credentials

Comment: could you check that thta user password hashed in your database ?

Comment: and check also that your form data comes correctly to your controller as you excpect

Comment: this is the problem because `attempt`  hash your password and compare it with your hashed password in database

Comment: so how to check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225857/discussion-between-joseph-and-hari-dran).